# openpyxl loop is not breaking when it is supposed to

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to write a method using openpyxl that finds the next unmerged cell without a value in a specified column and writes to it. `writeData()` is called three times for a line of downloaded data.

My current code (below) will randomly stop at the cell before the required cell, even if its value is not `None`, then breaks the loop. It will even do this for the rest of the row. This error usually happens when a few rows have already had data written above.

```
def writeData(column, data):
for cell in ws[column]:
    if cell.value == None:
        try:
            cell.value = data
            wb.save(workbookPath)
            break
        except:
            continue
```

[Here is a snapshot of the Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1cTA.png) that the code is working in. Interestingly, the error only happens in the F,G,H and O,P,Q column groups, which are both under 'Out'. Perhaps it is due to the formatting I have set in Excel?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: To help someone understand more about what I am trying to do, the goal is to call the method three times like this:

```
def enterTransaction(dateColumn, descriptColumn, amountColumn, transactionTuple):
writeData(dateColumn, transactionTuple[0])      # date
writeData(descriptColumn, transactionTuple[1])  # description
writeData(amountColumn, transactionTuple[2])    # amount
```

The tuple has the date, description, and amount of a bank transaction in that order. The column parameters look like 'X', the date and description are strings, and the amount is a float. The columns are decided if it is personal or business (the two merged cells at the top of the sheet), and if the amount is positive or negative ('In' or 'Out'). These columns do get chosen correctly.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I ran the code and worked fine or me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should probably debug the code without saving the workbook to see what's going on.

Comment: To check None, you should use `if cell.value is None:` instead of `if cell.value == None:`